# How do I dot source all files in a sub directory using $PSScriptroot in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to dot source all .ps1 files in a subdirectory, relative to the script.  It will be stored in a Git repo, so it's relative position shouldn't change.

My research so far has led me to using $PSScriptroot and adding my subdirectory to that.  It doesn't appear to be working.

The code I'm using is this.

and I've tried various forms offered from solutions on this site.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath Functions) | ForEach-Object {. $($_.FullName)}
```

When the script continues, I get the errors:

The term 'Confirm-GamInstalled' is not recognized as.....etc

I've now tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path . -ChildPath Functions) | ForEach-Object {. $($_.FullName)}
```

And this seems to work on the command line, but not from the script, I get the same errors.

Can anyone tell me why the $PSScriptroot doesn't seem to be working, and how I can solve/troubleshoot this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: The first code looks fine, but the subexpression is unnecessary, just do `. $_.FullName`. How does your command line session differ from the script? Different current directory, other commands executed before, ...?

Comment: Try outputting the path names as you dot-source them and see if / how they differ - that might give a clue to the cause. In its very simplest form, something like ```… | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName; . $($_.FullName) }``` will output the paths.